# Need regex expression in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I am writing the mysql query where I need to compare data entered by user with the sku column in database tab

Query is like

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `is_product_info` 
WHERE REPLACE(  '-',  '', sku ) LIKE  '%ETI2006%'
```

so that if sku in database contains "-" in sku, I am replacing all hyphens with "" before comparing.

so whether sju no contains ETI2006 or ETI-2006, it will come in output

Comment: so what would be your expected result ?

Comment: whether sku in database contains "-" or not, it should come in output

Comment: I think you may just like this
SELECT * 
FROM  `is_product_info` 
WHERE REPLACE( `sku` , '-',  '' ) LIKE  '%ETI2006%'

Comment: main point is in database, sku nos are simple like 'ETI2006' or some are like 'ETI-2006' (hyphen will be in any place say ETI200-6) 

So now user in front end, will mostly enters ETI2006 (no hyphen they are entering). I am comparing in query like sku like '%ETI2006%' (what user enters) but in database there are hyphens for some skus so no result is coming in some cases. 
I need query which will check for string with hyphen or without hyphens also

Comment: execute this 
 SELECT * FROM is_product_info WHERE REPLACE( sku , '-', '' ) LIKE '%ETI2006%'
i got output with this query as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may just like this

```
SELECT * FROM is_product_info WHERE REPLACE( sku , '-', '' ) LIKE '%ETI2006%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try on a running MySQL but this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `is_product_info` 
WHERE sku REGEXP REPLACE('ETI-2006','-','-?');
```

Comment: this returned so many rows around 49000.
It should return only rows containing either ETI-2006 or ETI2006 or any other sku containing these chars ETI2006

Comment: main point is in database, sku nos are simple like 'ETI2006' or some are like 'ETI-2006' (hyphen will be in any place say ETI200-6) 

So now user in front end, will mostly enters ETI2006 (no hyphen they are entering). I am comparing in query like sku like '%ETI2006%' (what user enters) but in database there are hyphens for some skus so no result is coming in some cases. 
I need query which will check for string with hyphen or without hyphens also

Comment: @user2321321 Please see my edited answer. I had written arguments in false order for REPLACE, now corrected

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake in replace syntax, it works with the below one:

SELECT * FROM is_product_info WHERE REPLACE( sku , '-', '' ) LIKE '%ETI2006%'

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace()` on every row is what's slowing it down.

All of these approaches should be faster - see which one works best for you:

Option 1 - use LIKE twice:

```
WHERE sku LIKE '%ETI-2006%'
   OR sku LIKE '%ETI2006%'
```

Option 2 - Use RLIKE once:

```
WHERE sku RLIKE 'ETI-?2006'
```